# passing in a list of strings to a jsf bean

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3, variadic-functions

In my JSF file, I have a command button that looks like this:

'< h:commandButton value="Start." action='#{myBean.startIt}'/>

startIt() is a method with no arguments that has a hardcoded ArrayList of Strings.

What I would really like to do is pass in a variable number of Strings to startIt(), and 
get rid of the hardcoding.

If I try the "vararg" syntax, e.g.

public void startIt(String... myStrings){
...}

I get the following error when I call the function with a even a single string:

wrong number of argumentswrong number of arguments
class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Any ideas on how to get varargs to work with JSF 2, or failing that, another solution to the underlying problem would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do this by specifying value in the f:param element and then reterving that value in backing bean:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{myBean.startIt}">
    <f:param name="request" value="AnyValue"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Backing Bean Code:

```
String request= (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("request");
```